# primeng tabview angular issue setting active tab in code

Tags: angular, primeng

I am using Primeng Tabview in my angular application. I have the code as shown below to set the active tab using code.

```
<button (click)="change(0)">First</button>
<button (click)="change(1)">Second</button>
<button (click)="change(2)">Third</button>

<p:tabView [activeIndex]="index" ...


public index: number;

change(index: number): void {
    this.index = index;
}
```

But as soon as I manually go to a tab and try to click on the button, it is not going to the right tab. Not sure what is wrong or how to make it work?

Comment: use square brackets at the same time.

Answer (score 8):

Update your `index` variable while changing tab manually.

**HTML**

```
<p-tabView [activeIndex]="index" (onChange)="handleChange($event)">...
```

**TS**

```
handleChange(e) {
  this.index = e.index;
}
```

See [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/cIeuepKmQxN84wL1hfX4?p=preview)

Answer (score 4):

Alternatively, use two-way binding:

```
<p-tabView [(activeIndex)]="index"></p-tabView>
```

Comment: I think this is correct answer because if you use only normal brackets, you use one way binding. To change index manually you need to you two way binding.